# Saxon XPath API returns TinyElementImpl instead of org.w3c.dom.Node

Tags: saxon, java, xpath-api

I have the following code:

```
// xpath evaluates to net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathEvaluator
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath(); 
XPathExpression expression = xpath.compile("/foo/bar");
Object evaluate = expression.evaluate(someXML, XPathConstants.NODE);
Object evaluate2 = expression.evaluate(someXML, XPathConstants.NODESET);

System.out.println(evaluate!=null?evaluate.getClass():"null");
System.out.println(evaluate2!=null?evaluate2.getClass():"null2");

System.out.println(evaluate instanceof Node);
System.out.println(evaluate2 instanceof NodeList);
```

and this is the result...

```
class net.sf.saxon.tinytree.TinyElementImpl
class java.util.ArrayList
false
false
```

**Just to clarify**, if I do this:

```
org.w3c.dom.Node node = (org.w3c.dom.Node)evaluate;
```

or

```
org.w3c.dom.NodeList node = (org.w3c.dom.NodeList)evaluate2;
```

I get a `ClassCastException`

How can that be? according to Suns Java 1.5 [API](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPathConstants.html#NODESET) NODE and NODESET should map to `org.w3c.dom.Node` and `org.w3c.dom.NodeList` respectively

**Just to clarify2** yes I know Node is an iterface, that getClass() returns a concrete class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok I figured it out!

If the evaluate method receives an InputSource the above error occurs.

e.g.

```
InputSource someXML = new InputSource(new StringReader("<someXML>...</someXML>)");
Object result = expression.evaluate(someXML, XPathConstants.NODE); 
Node node = (Node) result; // ClassCastException
```

Then result is not implementing `org.w3c.dom.Node` (`TinyElementImpl`)

But if evaluate receives a `Node` (or a `Document`):

```
DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document someXML = documentBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader("<someXML>...</someXML>)"));
Object result = expression.evaluate(someXML, XPathConstants.NODE);
Node node = (Node) result; // works
```

It works, but still, this is weird...

Comment: Makes sense.... if you put W3C DOM in, you get W3C DOM out. Otherwise, you get proprietary DOM out.

Answer (score 4):

Try this code:

```
Object evaluate = expression.evaluate(someXML, XPathConstants.NODE);
System.out.println(evaluate instanceof Node);
System.out.println(NodeOverNodeInfo.wrap((NodeInfo) evaluate) instanceof Node);
```

It prints:

```
false
true
```

The returned object is of type `NodeInfo`, so you need wrap it as a real `Node`, so you can access its methods:

```
Node n = NodeOverNodeInfo.wrap((NodeInfo) evaluate);
System.out.println(n.getNodeName());
System.out.println(n.getTextContent());
```

Comment: This works and is the most helpful answer on the page.  Well done!

Answer (score 2):

`Node` is an interface. You have to have a concrete class for implementation. And `getClass()` returns that concrete class.

Edit in response to comment:

Sorry, I didn't pay attention to the instanceof. Looking at the [source code](http://saxon.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/saxon/latest9.2/hej/net/sf/saxon/tinytree/TinyNodeImpl.java?revision=401&view=markup), it appears that `TinyNodeImpl` doesn't implement `org.w3c.dom.Node`. And looking at the JDK docs, it appears that it doesn't have to: the doc for [javax.xml.XPath](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html) refers you to [XPathConstants](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPathConstants.html) for the result type, and it refers to the "The XPath 1.0 NodeSet data type" (which, if you look at the XPath 1.0 spec, is not defined).

So, it seems that returns from the XPath API are only required to be consistent when used within that API. Not exactly what you wanted to hear, I'm sure. Can you use the built-in JDK implementation? I know that it returns `org.w3c.dom` objects.

Comment: Thanks, I'll clarify the question. And yes, I get a ClassCastException, you can tell that by the last 2 lines of the code (evaluate instanceof Node) if it is not instanceof, it doesn't implement that interface, thus a class cast exceptino will occur.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit odd, this one. The [Saxon javadoc](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/javadoc/index.html) says that `TinyElementImpl` doesn't implement any of the `org.w3c.dom` interfaces, and yet you're getting them back from the XPath evaluation.

My guess is that Saxon eschews the standard DOM model in favour of its own one. I suspect that the `XPathConstants.NODE` that you pass to `evaluate` is really just a hint. It's permitted for XPath expressions to return any old thing (for example, [Apache JXPath](http://commons.apache.org/jxpath/) uses XPath expressions to query java objects graphs), so it's permitted for Saxon to return its own DOM types rather than `org.w3c` standard ones.

Solution: either use the Saxon DOM types as returned, or don't use Saxon.

Answer (score -1):

kdgregory is correct that `Node` is just an interface, and `TinyElementImpl` implements that interface. `expression.evaluate()` can't return an instance of `Node`, it has to return a concrete class which *implements* node.

It might be useful to point out that you can use an instance of `TinyElementImpl` *as* as `Node`, and you can easily cast instances of `TinyElementImp` to `Node`.

For example, this should work just fine:

```
Node result = (Node) expression.evaluate(someXML, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

You can then use `result` by calling any of the methods of `Node`, and by passing it to any method which accepts a `Node`.

Comment: Please read the comment on kdgregory's answer. TinyElementImpl doesn't implement Node by the way.

Comment: OK, yeah, I see that I made an incorrect assumption.

Still, I think the spirit of my answer does address some aspects of the question in an honest effort to help.

I can live with the downvote though.